# How to use Event objects in python with a thread?

Tags: python, events, python-multithreading

I have a main python script which starts a thread running in the background.

`poll = threading.Thread(target=poll_files, args=myargs)`

I want my main script to wait until something specific happens in my `poll` thread. I want to use an Event object. So in my main script, I do:

`trigger = threading.Event()`

and when I want to wait:

`trigger.wait()`

My question is, inside my `poll` thread, how do I set the Event to True? I know I do:

`trigger.set()`

but do I need to also have `trigger = threading.Event()` inside my `poll` thread?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pass the `Event` object to the thread target function so that they are shared between main thread and the `pool` thread:

```
def poll_files(....., trigger):
    ....
    trigger.set()

# main thread
trigger = threading.Event()
poll = threading.Thread(target=poll_files, args=myargs + (trigger,))
...
trigger.wait()
```